# Not able to handle Filter and sort in a datagrid as separate events

Tags: gwt

Currently I have implemented a custom header for datagrid which includes a textbox for filtering and a header title. When i click on textbox, the column sorts and i am not able to filter. If i remove the sorting part, filtering works fine. Please suggest any ideas so that both filtering and sorting can be done. Below is my sample code. (Everything is not included, just i have shown relevant parts of code)

```
public class TextBoxHeader<T> extends Header<String> {

public TextBoxHeader(String title, String width) {
        super(new TextInputCell());
        this.title = title;
        if (width != null) {
            this.width = width;
        }
    }

@Override
    public void render(Context context, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {

        if (value == null) {
            value = "";
        }

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("<input type=\"text\" tabindex=\"-1\" value=\"" + value + "\" id=\"" + TEXT_BOX_ID
                + "\" style=\" width:130px");
        //stringBuilder.append(width);
        stringBuilder.append(" \" /> </input> <BR>");
        stringBuilder.append(title);
        sb.append(SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant(stringBuilder.toString()));
    }

@Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem, NativeEvent event) {
}
}

this sort event handler is in another class.
protected class DataGridSortEvent implements ColumnSortEvent.Handler {

        @Override
        public void onColumnSort(ColumnSortEvent event) {
            System.out.println("inside DataGridSortEvent-->"+event.isSortAscending());
            //customGrid.getDataProvider().refresh();
            Collections.sort(customGrid.getDataProvider().getList(), nameComparator);
            //customGrid.getDataProvider().refresh();

             /*sortHandler.setComparator(name, new Comparator<Person>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                        System.out.println("inside comparator");
                        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
                    }
                });*/

        }

    }

Any ideas to handle both (Sort and filter)???
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override onBrowserEvent, identify the source of the click (whether it is your text input or your header (which is there instead of a "sort" button if I get you right). I assume you have two different clickable elements for each action, of course.

The following code snippet just figure out if the cell's content was clicked or if the click happened on container (the cell itself). If the click happens on the input, do the filtering stuff. If it happens on the cell, do the sorting stuff.

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, T value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<T> valueUpdater) {
    // Handle the click event.
    super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    if (CLICK.equals(event.getType())) {
        // Ignore clicks that occur outside of the outermost element.
        EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
        Element eventElement = Element.as(eventTarget);
        NodeList<Element> listOfChildrens = parent.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfChildrens.getLength(); i++) {
            Element currentElement = listOfChildrens.getItem(i);
            if (currentElement.isOrHasChild(eventElement)) {
                // text is always inside a Text node =
                // element.childNodes[0].nodeValue.
                execute(value, eventElement.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More example of onBrowserEvent can be found on the [abstractCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10152/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractCell.html) page, and others.